# iOS: UIImage size in bytes is different than actual image size

Tags: ios, uikit, uiimage

I’m try to get the size in bytes of `UIImage`. The problem is that my actual image is of 5MB and when i get the size using

```
let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as! UIImage
let imgData = NSData(data: image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1)!)
var imageSize: Int = imgData.count
print("actual size of image in KB: %f ", Double(imageSize) / 1000.0)
```

I’m getting 2MB only. can anyone enlighten me on this please.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't this line recompress the image?

```swift
    let imgData = NSData(data: image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1)!)
```

If so, I'd definitely expect the resulting image to be smaller than the original.

Comment: its compressionQuality is 1 which means don't compress i guess. Is there any other way to get the size of image?

Comment: yes it does compress even if with 1.0 compression

Comment: I genuinely didn't think there was a way to get a jpeg representation without _some_  compression - I don't think the format lets you do that!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me instead of `UIImage().jpegdata`

```
  public func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    var asset: PHAsset!
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
      asset = info[UIImagePickerControllerPHAsset] as? PHAsset
    } else {
      if let url = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as? URL {
        asset = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withALAssetURLs: [url], options: .none).firstObject!
      }
    }

    if #available(iOS 13, *) {
      PHImageManager.default().requestImageDataAndOrientation(for: asset, options: .none) { data, string, orien, info in
        let imgData = NSData(data:data!)
        var imageSize: Int = imgData.count
        print("actual size of image in KB: %f ", Double(imageSize) / 1024.0)
      }
    } else {
      PHImageManager.default().requestImageData(for: asset, options: .none) { data, string, orientation, info in
        let imgData = NSData(data:data!)
        var imageSize: Int = imgData.count
        print("actual size of image in KB: %f ", Double(imageSize) / 1024.0)
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add option .original to the PHImageRequestOptions. This one should do the trick:

```
let options = PHImageRequestOptions()
options.deliveryMode = .highQualityFormat
options.resizeMode = .none
options.version = .original
        
        
PHImageManager.default().requestImageDataAndOrientation(for: asset, options: options)
```